# SQL Server 2008 Hierarchy Data Type Performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, hierarchy

How does SQL Server 2008's Hierarchy data type perform compared to using the hierarchy implementation described by Joe Celko here: http://www.intelligententerprise.com/001020/celko.jhtml?

I've used Celko's method in the past with great results - but don't want to implement it for a new project unless it's better than what Microsoft has provided in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Excellent question, looking forward to finding out the answer

Answer (score 4):

So far, I've only found a single reasonably interesting article on the topic. HierarchyId is much faster than any self-made self-referencing table solution:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/62204/

I vaguely remember seeing another comparison elsewhere (but can't find it anymore) which came to similar conclusions; using HierarchyId to build up the hierarchy is a bit cumbersome at best, but query performance is stellar.

Marc

Comment: This is an interesting article, however they are not comparing to Celko's nested sets. Celko's sets are WAY better for storage than self referencing columns - which result in recursive calls.