# How design SQL tables for these requirements

Tags: sql, database-design

I have data as `CITY` and `AREA`.

1. Each `CITY` has multiple `AREAS`
2. Each `AREA` has multiple `AREAS` (here there is no end, dynamically user can add `AREAS` under the child `AREA` like `AREA->AREA->Area->AREA....->AREA`)

So, how to design such table structure which satisfy these requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does each area has multiple CHILD areas, multiple PARENT areas, or both?

Answer (score 2):

**City Table**

- CityID (PK)
- CityName

**City Areas Table**

- CityID     (Composite (two-column) PKey)
- AreaID     (Add a Unique Index to this column, if you want an area to be ownable by only one city)

**Areas Table**

- AreaID (PK)
- AreaName

**Area Area Mapping Table**

- AreaID     (Owner Area)   (Composite (two-column) PKey)
- AreaID

**Rules**

- In order to map one area to another, there must be a record for each area in the Areas table.
- In the Area Area Mapping Table, you must determine if these relationships are two-way or one-way. In my opinion, it will be one way. The first AreaID is the area that owns the second AreaID.

Comment: In your example an Area can belong to many cities and to many areas also. In what he describes, it looks like only a city can have many areas, and an area can have many child areas. These are one-to-many relationships, not many-to-many

Comment: Good point, fixed w/ unique index ON Cita Areas table. However, I don't believe we can rule out that one Area may be owned by more than one Area. Example: The Park is owned by The Block, and The Block is owned by The Neighborhood. While it's be best to have a chain of ownership, the question was a bit fuzzy here.

Comment: Note, technically City Areas could have a PKey on AreaID alone if an Area can only be owned by one City. However, for understandability for other coders, I'd probably leave the two-column PKEY and unique constraint in place.

Comment: Adding the unique composite PK does not solve the many-to-many issue. Example AreaId 20, CityId 30 and AreaId 20 with CityId 40 - those are both uniques as pair and the Area 20 belongs to two cities (30 and 40) which is not good - the same is the case with AreaArea table. Your design permits an area to have multiple parents - mine does not permit that

Comment: You did not understand my first comment (I did not type clearly). I added a Unique Index to the AreaID on the City Areas table. That solves the problem.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right - that solves the problem, but then, that table is redundant (its in a relation of 1 to 1 with the Area table without adding any additional info)

Comment: That table is redundant, true. However, like my composite PKey on that same table, I believe the DB is more understandable this way for other coders. That said, you are absolutely correct

Comment: Pivot tables (the ones that contain composite primary keys) are used for m to n relationships - its confusing when someone is using them to model 1-to-n relationships

Comment: You have  good point, but keep in mind that 9 out of 10 Areas, or perhaps 99 out of 100 Areas, may end up with NULL in their CityID field.

Answer (score 1):

table **AREA**:

- id (PK)
- parent_area_id - the area to which it belongs - can be NULL if no parent area (FK on AREA table)
- city_id  - the city to which it belongs - you can enforce from your business logic that a city_id to be NULL if parent_area_id is completed, or vice versa (FK on city table)
- other useful columns

table **CITY**:

- id (PK)
- other useful info

You might be interested in reading about [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) - it also applies to other DB engines

Comment: +1 for mentioning nested sets (in link). I've not tried them, but it looks like they could be **much** faster in certain scenarios. Here is [an article on the subject](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html)  from Joe Celko

Answer (score 1):

That would be a tree (or possibly a hierarchy). The most common solution, which you will see in other answers here, is to use the adjacency list model. However, the other 'big' idea to consider is the nested sets model. A useful book on the subject is [Joe Celko's Trees and hierarchies in SQL](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uw2lq2o4VbUC&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 1):

Reflexive relationship.

[image]

Or, if you prefer **[nested sets](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2008 the choice is the hierarchy data type

Here is a link about the [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045743/sql-server-2008-hierarchy-data-type-performance)