# Flattening a SQL hierarchical data structure in SQL without cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

Let's say I have the following table

```
SectionID ParentIDSection DatumID
   1           NULL         1
   2            1           2
   3            1           3
   4            2           4
```

Now, let's  pretend I want to select all DatumIDs under SectionID = 1, even if it is part of its descendants children so that I would get

```
SectionID DatumID
  1         1
  1         2
  1         3
  1         4
```

Is it possible to this without explicitly iterating over the first table recursively with a cursor?

Comment: [Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This confused me for a minute because it was kind of going the opposite direction of how I think about recursion, but I came up with this solution that is pretty simple:

```
;WITH Rollups AS (
    SELECT SectionId, ParentIdSection, DatumId
    FROM SectionDataTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT parent.SectionId, parent.ParentIdSection, child.DatumId
    FROM SectionDataTable parent 
    INNER JOIN Rollups child ON child.ParentIdSection = parent.SectionId
)
SELECT *
FROM Rollups 
WHERE SectionID = 1
```

(Replace with the section id you want)

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @demo table
(
    SectionId int not null primary key clustered
    , ParentId int null --foreign key references @demo(SectionId)
    , DatumId int
);

insert @demo
      select 1, null, 1
union select 2, 1, 2
union select 3, 1, 3
union select 4, 2, 4
union select 5, null, 5
union select 6, 5, 6
;

with demoHierarchy
as
(
    select SectionId
    , SectionId ParentId
    , SectionId OriginalAncestorId
    , DatumId
    from @demo
    where ParentId is null --remove this line if you want OriginalAncestorId to be AnyAncestorId (if that doesn't make sense, try it and see)

    union all

    select d.SectionId
    , d.ParentId
    , h.OriginalAncestorId
    , d.DatumId
    from @demo d
    inner join demoHierarchy h
    on d.ParentId = h.SectionId
    where d.ParentId is not null --implied by the join, but here to make it explicit
)
select OriginalAncestorId SectionId
, DatumId 
from demoHierarchy
where OriginalAncestorId = 1 --not needed given your sample data only contains this data, but required when you have multiple root ancestors
```

More info on hierarchical queries available here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Hierarchy ID in MS SQL 2008.  Another question was asked about relative performance at [SQL Server 2008 Hierarchy Data Type Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045743/sql-server-2008-hierarchy-data-type-performance).

Here is another reference on handling recursive hierarchies: http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/09/handling-recursive-hierarchies-in-sql-server/